# How to remove spaces from double curly brackets in Angular using linter?

Tags: angular, eslint, lint, prettier, curly-braces

How to lint/format the Angular template containing [value interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation) or [pipe](https://angular.io/api/core/Pipe) and remove possible spaces after `{{` and before `}}` double curly brackets?

Input:

```
<div>{{ foo}}</div>
```

Desired Output:

```
<div>{{foo}}</div>
```

So far I haven't found any [Prettier](https://prettier.io/), nor [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) rules for this.

Prettier can only add spaces and has closed [defect #5478](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/5478). I assume ESLint [probably won't cover](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint/blob/main/docs/FORMATTING_RULES.md) this at all.

It seems Angular Docs itself is a bit inconsistent in using spaces around curly brackets, but I would like to normalize this for my projects and remove those spaces.

Comment: Do that manually.

Comment: Have you check ESLint `object-curly-spacing`? https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/object-curly-spacing

Comment: @ShayD Yes, thank you. It seems to ignore double-curly braces…